# Upload Image Data as a File w/o File Input Control

Tags: javascript, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an image to a web server .aspx page; the server side uses this mechanism to recognize the file:

```
HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[0];
```

I can't change the server code because there are other clients.

Working Javascript/Angular code that can upload from an HTML file input control:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById('the-file');
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);
(etc)

$http.post(uploadUrl, formData, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
    transformRequest: angular.identity })
```

All well and good.  What I need to figure out, though, is how to upload content from an image that the user has cropped on the client side (and thus the cropped image is no longer affiliated with an HTML file input control).  It's in a Canvas, and I know how to get it as a DataUri or an arraybuffer or even a byte array.  I just can't figure out how to upload it to this server endpoint so it will be recognized on the server side as a posted file.  Is this possible?  I don't know how to properly replace the following line:

```
formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);
```